# Emberjs "eq" in component

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

Got a component that works just fine as follows (selectedId is definitely set):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    items: [],
    selectedId: 0,
    result: '',
    init () {
        this._super(...arguments);
        var store = this.get('store'); 
        let items =  store.findAll('dealtype');
        this.set('items', items);
    },
    didInsertElement: function() {
       // this.$().select2();
     }
});
```

This render my component fine, but the part it never goes to true for the if statement (installed ember-truth-helpers for that)

```
<select style="width:100%">
    <option value=""></option>
    {{#each items as |item|}}
        {{#if (eq selectedId item.id)}}
            <option selected="selected" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}} YEAH</option>
        {{else}}
            <option  value="{{item.id}}"> {{item.name}} </option>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Don't want to mix problems, but as you see i commented out the select2 init call.  When doing that it make my select a select2 list, but the items are gone (thought still in the markup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend that you use Ember Power select component since they have solved everything you need for Select component

http://www.ember-power-select.com/

They have two component for single select entry and multiple. There is a good documentation and great support for ember cli projects

https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select

As for your problem I would try this - I have not tested itbut form top of my head this should solve your issue:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
  this._super();
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
},
afterRenderEvent : function(){
var component = this;
Ember.run.later((function() {
  Ember.$('select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    delay: 250}).on('select2-open', function() {}
  })
});
```

So what you need to use is aaferRenderEvent and run later to init your select 2 component. Please check aboe the code if all {} are properly closed. But this will get your select2 working insdie ember project.

Hope it helps.